# APA style in et al. format conversion

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style, author-number

I want to generate the APA style reference in et al. format as shown under which I got from endnote… But when try in LaTeX I am getting all authors name typed up as shown below…

Here I am attaching my `.tex` file, `.bib` file and output file…

Output from my word document by using endnote

> bla bla bla bla (Powers, Young et al. 2003 ; Heitjan 2011), bla bla bla (Fleischhacker, Derks et al. 2012; Nakash, Hutton et al. 2008) and social science studies(Green, Murphy et al. 2000; Hamano Yamaski et al. 2011)

Output from my LaTeX file

> bla bla bla bla (Powers, Young, Russell, & Pachana, 2003;
>   Heitjan, 2011) , bla bla bla (Fleischhacker, Derks, & Kahn,
>   2012; Nakash, Hutton, Lamb, Gates, & Fisher, 2008) and social
>   science studies (Green, Murphy, & Snyder, 2000; Hamano et al.,
>   2011)

My `.tex` file

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\par bla bla bla bla ~\cite{Powers03, Heitjan11} , bla bla bla ~\cite{Fleischhacker12, Nakash08} and social science studies~\cite{Green00, Hamano11}

\newpage
\label{REFERENCES}
\nocite{*}
\lhead{\emph{Bibliography}} % Change the page header to say "Bibliography"



\bibliography{Bibliography1} % The references (bibliography) information are stored in the file named "Bibliography.bib"
\end{document}
```

My `.bib` file

```
@article{Acock05,
author = {Acock, Alan C.},
title = {Working With Missing Values},
journal = {Journal of Marriage \& Family},
volume = {67},
number = {4},
pages = {1012-1028},
year = {2005}
}

@article{baker88,
author = {Baker, Stuart G. and Laird, Nan M.},
title = {Regression Analysis for Categorical Variables With Outcome Subject to Nonignorable Nonresponse},
journal = {Journal of the American Statistical Association},
volume = {83},
number = {401},
pages = {62},
year = {1988}
}

@book{Bishop95,
author = {Bishop, Yvonne M. M. and Fienberg, Stephen E. and Holland, Paul W.},
title = {Discrete Multivariate Analysis : Theory and Practice},
publisher = {MIT Press},
pages = {560p.},
year = {1995}
}

@article{Blumenthal68,
author = {Blumenthal, Saul},
title = {MULTINOMIAL SAMPLING WITH PARTIALLY CATEGORIZED DATA},
journal = {Journal of the American Statistical Association},
volume = {63},
number = {322},
pages = {542},
year = {1968}
}

@book{Carpenter13,
author = {Carpenter, James R., Kenward Michael G.},
title = {Multiple imputation and its application},
publisher = {Wiley},
edition = {1st edition},
year = {2013}
}

@article{Elashoff47,
author = {Elashoff, Janet DixonElashoff R. M.},
journal = {Journal of the Royal Statistical Society: Series C (Applied Statistics)},
volume = {23},
number = {1},
pages = {26},
year = {1974}
}

@article{Fay86,
author = {Fay, Robert E.},
title = {Causal Models for Patterns of Nonresponse},
journal = {Journal of the American Statistical Association},
volume = {81},
number = {394},
pages = {354},
year = {1986}
}

@article{Fleischhacker12,
author = {Fleischhacker, W. Wolfgang and Derks, Eske and Kahn, Rene S.},
title = {Interpreting treatment trials in schizophrenia patients: lessons learned from EUFEST},
journal = {Schizophrenia Research},
volume = {138},
number = {1},
pages = {39-40},
year = {2012}
}

@article{Green00,
author = {Green, Robert G. and Murphy, Katrina D. and Snyder, Shelita M.},
title = {Should demographics be placed at the end or at the beginning of mailed questionnaires? An empirical answer to a persistent methodological question},
journal = {Social Work Research},
volume = {24},
number = {4},
pages = {237-241},
year = {2000}
}

@article{Hamano11,
author = {Hamano, Tsuyoshi and Yamasaki, Masayuki and Fujisawa, Yoshikazu and Ito, Katsuhisa and Nabika, Toru and Shiwaku, Kuninori},
title = {Social capital and psychological distress of elderly in Japanese rural communities},
journal = {Stress \& Health: Journal of the International Society for the Investigation of Stress},
volume = {27},
number = {2},
pages = {163-169},
year = {2011}
}

@article{Heitjan11,
author = {Heitjan, Daniel F.},
title = {Incomplete Data: What You Don't Know Might Hurt You},
journal = {Cancer Epidemiology, Biomarkers \& Prevention},
volume = {20},
number = {8},
pages = {1567-1570},
year = {2011}
}

@article{Hocking71,
author = {Hocking, R. R. and Oxspring, H. H.},
title = {Maximum Likelihood Estimation with Incomplete Multinomial Data},
journal = {Journal of the American Statistical Association},
volume = {66},
number = {333},
pages = {65},
year = {1971}
}

@article{Johnson11,
author = {Johnson, David R. and Young, Rebekah},
title = {Toward Best Practices in Analyzing Datasets with Missing Data: Comparisons and Recommendations},
journal = {Journal of Marriage \& Family},
volume = {73},
number = {5},
pages = {926-945},
year = {2011}
}

@article{Koch72,
author = {Koch, G. G. and Imrey, P. B. and Reinfurt, D. W.},
title = {Linear model analysis of categorical data with incomplete response vectors},
journal = {Biometrics},
volume = {28},
number = {3},
pages = {663-692},
year = {1972}
}

@article{Little82,
author = {Little, Roderick J. A.},
title = {Models for Nonresponse in Sample Surveys},
journal = {Journal of the American Statistical Association},
volume = {77},
number = {378},
pages = {237},
year = {1982}
}

@book{Little02,
author = {Little, Roderick J. A. , Rubin Donald B. },
title = {Statistical analysis with missing data},
publisher = {Hoboken N. J. Wiley},
edition = {2nd Edition},
year = {2002}
}

@book{McKnight07,
author = {McKnight, P. E. and McKnight, K. M. and Sidani, S. and Figueredo, A. J.},
title = {Missing data: a gentle introduction},
publisher = {Guilford Publications Guilford Press},
address = {New York, New York},
series = {Methodology in the Social Sciences},
pages = {251 p},
year = {2007}
}

@article{Meyer76,
author = {Meyer, M. B. and Jonas, B. S. and Tonascia, J. A.},
title = {Perinatal events associated with maternal smoking during pregnancy},
journal = {American Journal Of Epidemiology},
volume = {103},
number = {5},
pages = {464-476},
year = {1976}
}

@book{Molenberghs06,
author = {Molenberghs Geert, Kenward Michael G.},
title = {Missing data in clinical studies},
publisher = {Wiley InterScience Publication},
address = {Hoboken, N. J.},
year = {2006}
}

@article{Nakash08,
author = {Nakash, Rachel A. and Hutton, Jane L. and Lamb, Sarah E. and Gates, Simon and Fisher, Joanne},
title = {Response and non-response to postal questionnaire follow-up in a clinical trial – a qualitative study of the patient’s perspective},
journal = {Journal of Evaluation in Clinical Practice},
volume = {14},
number = {2},
pages = {226-235},
year = {2008}
}

@article{Powers03,
author = {Powers, Jennifer R. and Young, Anne F. and Russell, Anne and Pachana, Nancy A.},
title = {Implications of Non-Response of Older Women to a Short Form of the Center for Epidemiologic Studies Depression Scale},
journal = {International Journal of Aging and Human Development},
volume = {57},
number = {1},
pages = {37-54},
year = {2003}
}

@techreport{Puma09,
author = {Puma, Michael J. and Olsen, Robert B. and Bell, Stephen H. and Price, Cristofer and National Center for Education, Evaluation and Regional, Assistance},
title = {What to Do when Data Are Missing in Group Randomized Controlled Trials. NCEE 2009-0049},
institution = {National Center for Education Evaluation and Regional Assistance},
year = {2009}
}

@article{Raghunathan04,
author = {Raghunathan, Trivellore E.},
title = {WHAT DO WE DO WITH MISSING DATA?SOME OPTIONS FOR ANALYSIS OF INCOMPLETE DATA},
journal = {Annual Review of Public Health},
volume = {25},
number = {1},
pages = {99-117},
year = {2004}
}

@article{Shih87,
author = {Shih, W. J.},
title = {Maximum likelihood estimation and likelihood ratio test for square tables with missing data},
journal = {Statistics In Medicine},
volume = {6},
number = {1},
pages = {91-97},
year = {1987}
}

@article{Stasny86,
author = {Stasny, Elizabeth A.},
title = {Estimating Gross Flows Using Panel Data With Nonresponse: An Example From the Canadian Labour Force Survey},
journal = {Journal of the American Statistical Association},
volume = {81},
number = {393},
pages = {42},
year = {1986}
}
```

Comment: Do you want a citation style where you show the names of the first two authors whenever there are four or more authors? That's what your `endnote` examples seem to be suggesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though i am having trouble reading your question, From what i have understood, Did you try using [`apacite`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/apacite) package in your document's preamble ?  Please check also the `natbib` package which has a description to achieve the option you want using `\citep{ref}` in the [wikibooks of latex](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management). One working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

This information was taken from~\citep{goossens93}.

\bibliography{test}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{document}
```

And the `test.bib` contains:

```
@Book{goossens93,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
```

And the output it produces:

> This information was taken from [Goossens et al., 1993]

Comment: yes its not working the way I want it.. Its printing all the authors name instead of et all format

Comment: Thanks its working... I was just using \cite but it works pretty good with \citep