# Unable to cite in text APA style reference

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

I am unable to cite references in APA style. Below is the code. Can somebody please show how to correctly cite references? In the output pdf I am getting `The Authors in (?,?)` instead of the correct `The Authors in (Kumar & Zhang, 2007)` and

```
References
Kumar, A., & Zhang, D. (15–20 April 2007). Biometric Recognition
using Entropy-Based Discretization. Acoustics, Speech
and Signal Processing, 2007. ICASSP 2007. IEEE International
Conference on. 2, pp. 125–128
```

This is the latex code. Please help. Thank you

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa}
%\documentclass[man]{apa}
%\documentclass[doc]{apa}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{apacite}
%\usepackage{biblatex-apa}
%these next packages extend the apa class to allow for including statistical and graphic commands
\usepackage{url}   %this allows us to cite URLs in the text
\usepackage{graphicx}  %allows for graphic to float when doing jou or doc style
\usepackage{amssymb}  %use formatting tools  for math symbols
% type setting of functions, packages, and R follows a particular style
\let\proglang=\textsf
\newcommand{\R}{\proglang{R}}
\newcommand{\pkg}[1]{{\normalfont\fontseries{b}\selectfont #1}}
\newcommand{\Rfunction}[1]{{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\fun}[1]{{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\Robject}[1]{{\texttt{#1}}}
%
%
%Here is where we start the important APA stuff

\title{How to write in APA style}
\author{Latex writer}
\affiliation{Department of Psychology \\ Northwestern University}
%taken from AP's user notes
% John Vokey uses something like this

\ifapamodeman{%

\note{\begin{flushleft}

  William Revelle\\

    Department of Psychology\\

  Northwestern University\\

 Evanston, Illinois\\

    60201\\

    e-mail: revelle@northwestern.edu\\



   \end{flushleft}}}

{%else, i.e., in jou and doc mode

%\note{Draft of \today}
}

\abstract{Template to write in APA format
}
\rightheader{Odd-Numbered Page Header}
\leftheader{Even-Numbered Page Header}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Advantage}

 The Authors in \cite{Kumar:07}, 

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\begin{thebibliography}{4}

\bibitem[1]{Kumar:07} Kumar, A., \& Zhang, D. (15--20 April 2007). Biometric Recognition using Entropy-Based Discretization. Acoustics, Speech and Signal Processing, 2007. ICASSP 2007. IEEE International Conference on. 2, pp. 125--128
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ehm... According to me, correct me if I'm wrong, when you use the `thebibliography` environment you put the citations **manually**, so while it is easy to do, is not recommended if there are options that do it automatically as `bibtex` and better yet, `biblatex`. I think you're confusing things a bit, since the package `apacite` works for `bibtex`.

Comment: **In a nutschell** create a reference database file (that uses the `*.bib` extension) for [bibtex](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#BibTeX), use the `apacite` package and at the end of your document or where you want to put your references add these lines: `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` and \bibliography{<name of your *.bib file **without** extension>} and compile it using `pdflatex` once, later compile it with `bibtex` and at least once more with `pdflatex` for you can see the references listed right.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a misunderstanding over how to use bibtex-style bibliography and style files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`apacite` does not work with a simple bibliography contained in the file, it needs an external `bib` file containing the references in `bibtex` format.  The reason for this is that it needs the structure of such an entry to extract data such as author and year.  A `bib` entry for your article might look like

```
@InProceedings{Kumar:07,
  author =   {Kumar, A. and Zhang, D.},
  title =    {Biometric Recognition using Entropy-Based
                  Discretization},
  booktitle =    {Acoustics, Speech and Signal Processing,
                  2007. ICASSP 2007.  (15--20 April 2007)},
  year =     2007,
  number =   2,
  series =   {IEEE Internation Conference},
  pages =    {125--128}
}
```

where you can see these fields are clearly marked.   If you put this in `mybib.bib` then you obtain the following output

[image: Sample output]

from

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa}
%\documentclass[man]{apa}
%\documentclass[doc]{apa}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{apacite}
%\usepackage{biblatex-apa}
%these next packages extend the apa class to allow for including statistical and graphic commands
\usepackage{url}   %this allows us to cite URLs in the text
\usepackage{graphicx}  %allows for graphic to float when doing jou or doc style
\usepackage{amssymb}  %use formatting tools  for math symbols
% type setting of functions, packages, and R follows a particular style
\let\proglang=\textsf
\newcommand{\R}{\proglang{R}}
\newcommand{\pkg}[1]{{\normalfont\fontseries{b}\selectfont #1}}
\newcommand{\Rfunction}[1]{{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\fun}[1]{{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\Robject}[1]{{\texttt{#1}}}
%
%
%Here is where we start the important APA stuff

\title{How to write in APA style}
\author{Latex writer}
\affiliation{Department of Psychology \\ Northwestern University}
%taken from AP's user notes
% John Vokey uses something like this

\ifapamodeman{%

\note{\begin{flushleft}

  William Revelle\\

    Department of Psychology\\

  Northwestern University\\

 Evanston, Illinois\\

    60201\\

    e-mail: revelle@northwestern.edu\\



   \end{flushleft}}}

{%else, i.e., in jou and doc mode

%\note{Draft of \today}
}

\abstract{Template to write in APA format
}
\rightheader{Odd-Numbered Page Header}
\leftheader{Even-Numbered Page Header}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Advantage of Symbolic Time series}

 The Authors in \cite{Kumar:07}, 

\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

Note the way the file is set-up doesn't require a `\bibliographystyle` command, in contrast to other packages.

For the above example the generated `.bbl` file is:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem [\protect \citeauthoryear {%
Kumar%
\ \BBA {} Zhang%
}{%
Kumar%
\ \BBA {} Zhang%
}{%
{\protect \APACyear {2007}}%
}]{%
Kumar:07}
\APACinsertmetastar {%
Kumar:07}%
\begin{APACrefauthors}%
Kumar, A.%
\BCBT {}\ \BBA {} Zhang, D.%
\end{APACrefauthors}%
\unskip\
\newblock
\APACrefYearMonthDay{2007}{}{}.
\newblock
{\BBOQ}\APACrefatitle {Biometric Recognition using Entropy-Based
  Discretization} {Biometric recognition using entropy-based
  discretization}.{\BBCQ}
\newblock
\BIn{} \APACrefbtitle {Acoustics, Speech and Signal Processing, 2007. ICASSP
  2007. (15--20 April 2007)} {Acoustics, speech and signal processing, 2007.
  icassp 2007. (15--20 april 2007)}\ (\BPGS\ 125--128).
\PrintBackRefs{\CurrentBib}

\end{thebibliography}
```

which shows the complicated structure that `apacite` expects of its bibliographies and why using `bibtex` is the recommended root.

Comment: Thank you for such a lucid and detailed answer. Could you please let me know if it is possible to get numbered References for example [1], [2]. Another request, if you don't mind could you please edit the title from "Advantage of Symbolic Time series" in the image that you uploaded to just "Advantage". It was my mistake to keep that heading in the first place. This is required as it is an unpublished work. Will be grateful.

Comment: Q2: I noticed that the et.al is not getting displayed when there are more than 3 Authors. Could you please provide a way out for this?

Comment: The style is set-up to meet the journal specifications, so only Author-Year is allowed, and et al. is used when there are 6 or more authors.  You can write `author = {Author, O. and Author, T. and others}` in the bib file to circumvent the last limitation.  As for the edit you suggest, it is not worth doing as it is not relevant to the issue here.

Comment: In this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135541/apa-style-in-et-al-format-conversion?rq=1 the et. al problem h as been resolved using the \usepackage{natbib} . When I included this package along with the existing \usepackage{apacite}, there were errors indicating incorrect cite style in \cite{key}

Comment: That uses `natbib` instead of `apacite`.  It will not produce the `apa` style.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, the references need to be in BibTeX format. For writing in APA style, you might also be interested in the `apa6` package, which for referencing requires a move to the newer `biblatex-apa` (and biber). This allows for full APA6 referencing (with UTF-8 support, reducing the need for LaTeX code in your .bib), and the documentation for `biblatex-apa` is excellent. The docs clearly show how to reference all the examples from the APA Manual 6th Edition (from chapters 6 and 7). Here are a couple of useful references for constructing your BibTeX file;

- [BibTeX Field Entry Guide](http://axon.cs.byu.edu/~adam/gatheredinfo/tips/bibtexentries.php) (which types need/support which entries)
- [Case Preservation of BibTeX entries](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Preserving_case_of_letters) (necessary for APA styles that change case, and good practice anyway).